# First number in list a variable isn't larger than

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there a quick way that doesn't involve a bunch of if-statements to get the first element in a list that my variable isn't bigger than? For example, if

```
x = 50
compare = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

I want this to return 64. My list will also be written in increasing order, so not every element in the list will need to be compared.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? `next(value for value in compare if value > x)` would do it, for example. Given increasing order you could also consider a bisection search. For those specific values, there's an even faster numerical approach (square the integer larger than the square root of x).

Comment: What do you consider to be "a bunch of if statements"?  You only need one, inside a loop.

Comment: I did an element-wise comparison, so almost as many if-statements as there are elements. Pretty much the longest possible way to do it. Both of your methods work great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Guys this is a new person to the language.  I think what your looking for is a for loop and a comparison and the use of the break keyword when the comparison indicates the state your looking for.

Comment: `compare[bisect.bisect_left(compare, x)]` - and no 'if-statements'. [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

Answer (score 5):

There's a short way of doing this that doesn't involve any `for` loop:

```
>>> x = 50
>>> compare = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>> next(item for item in compare if item >=x)
64
```

This creates an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#iterators) of values that are `>= x`, and then selects the first one.

Comment: sure it's a generator expression, but still a `for` loop really

Comment: I disagree. While it is still an iterative construct, it's not a for loop, and I think it's far more concise and expressive. Opinions vary, of course, and if you're not a fan of functional programming you may find a simple more loop more obvious.

Comment: It's a for loop. It literally says `for`. Also it has the same time complexity.

Comment: You seem really attached to that theory. So, sure. It's *totally* the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop. Test each element, and break out of the loop when you find what you're looking for.

```
result = None
for el in compare:
    if x < el:
        result = el
        break
if result is not None:
    print('Found', result)
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = 50
compare = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81] )

compare[compare>=x][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `while` loop:

```
count = 0
while x < compare[count]:
    count += 1
print(compare[count])
```